# Is it possible to read a certain number of characters after a certain number of digits from the start of the file

Tags: php

I'm setting up a web app, where users can choose the starting point and the number of characters to read from a text file containing 1 billion digits of pi.

I have looked, but I can't find any similar problems. Because I don't know what the starting digit is, I can't use other solutions.

Here is the function written in Python:

```
def pi(left : int, right : int):
    f.seek(left+1)
    return f.read(right)
```

For example, entering 700 as the starting point and 9 as the number of characters should return "Pi(700,9): 542019956".

Comment: php has fseek() and fread() jsut like python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fseek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to move the file pointer to the position you need, and [fread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to read the amount of characters you need - just like your Python sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this capability is built in to `file_get_contents`.

```
$substr = file_get_contents('pi_file.txt', false, null, 700, 9);
```

<sub>A handy feature of that function that I learned about *just now* after using it for the past 7 years.</sub>